# node.js String.split() disregard separator if between quotation marks

Tags: node.js, string, split, discord.js

So I want to create a discord bot command with node.js, where some parameters are given. The main idea is to use the command like this

```
/item create name:"Test Item" price:0 stock:infinite
```

Now I need to split the string, so every value can get attached. It's easy for

```
price:0
```

and

```
stock:infinite
```

But when splitting

```
name:"Test Item"
```

it will get separated into

```
name:"Test
```

and

```
Item"
```

Can I somehow disregard the space-separator between two quotation marks, so that

```
name"Test Item"
```

would stay the same. Otherwise, which method could be effectively used for sticking variables inside quotation marks together?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), and it looks like this

```js
const str = '/item create name:"Test Item" price:0 stock:infinite';
const rgx = /\w+:(\".+\"|\w+)/g;
const matches = str.match(rgx);

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Well, I tried it, and it really does what I want, but anything after those quotation marks get's included as one string. For example, I made
Console.log(matches[0]);
If there's anything else with quotation marks, it gives me 
name:"Test Item" price:0 stock:infinite desc:"Testing this command"
back, for the command 
/item create name:"Test Item" price:0 stock:infinite desc:"Testing this command"
as it sees everything as one parameter

Comment: @TheRaspbian I'm not sure I understand. `console.log(matches[0])` only gives `name:"Test Item"`. It's matching exactly what's asked in your question. Is there some other criteria that's not included?

Comment: No, it works fine, if there is only one parameter where you use quotation marks, it's fine. But if you use two ore more parameters with quotation marks, everything between the first "quotation-parameter" and the last, including them, counts as one.
So
name:"Test" desc:"Description" shop:true
would give me 
name:"Test" desc:"Description"
as one parameter, and 
shop:true
as the other one. if switching the params to
name:"Test" shop:true desc:"Description" 
then the
shop:true
is in between the quotation params and that counts as one params:
name:"Test" shop:true desc:"Description"

Answer (score 0):

This is your code snippet, but edited, so the last parameter is desc:"This is a test". so 'price:0 stock:infinite' gets added to the first parameter, which I want to prevent

```js
const str = '/item create name:"Test Item" price:0 stock:infinite desc:"This is a test"';
const rgx = /\w+:(\".+\"|\w+)/g;
const matches = str.match(rgx);

console.log(matches);
```